# /app/.heroku/python/bin/python: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python: cannot execute binary file

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework, heroku-cli

When I tried running

```
heroku run bash python manage.py migrate --app appName
```

from my terminal using the Heroku CLI, I get below error/response;

```
/app/.heroku/python/bin/python: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python: cannot execute binary file
```

-- Updated with screenshot --

Even when I tried `heroku run python manage.py migrate --app appName` without adding bash, I still get an error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get around this by first getting into bash on heroku, then running the command I wish to. Steps are listed below;

1. I open my terminal and using the heroku-cli, I ran `heroku run bash --app appName`
2. You should see the bash shell loaded if this execute successfully, looking something like  `~ $`
3. Now go ahead and manually enter your command, in this case `python manage.py migrate` which should work.
4. Just a tip --  if that doesn't still work (or you're just curious to see your file directory) you can go ahead and list out the different dirs to see where your manage.py file is before going into that correct dir and running your command again. Use `ls -l $(ls)` or `find . -maxdepth 3 -type d -ls` or simply `ls -l`

Answer (score 1):

This command doesn't make sense:

```
heroku run bash python manage.py migrate --app appName
```

Let's break it down:

- `heroku run ... --app appName` tells Heroku to run the stuff in `...` on the app `appName`
- `python manage.py migrate` is the command you want to run on your dyno:

  - `python` is the executable
  - `manage.py` is the file Python executes
  - `migrate` is an argument passed to `manage.py`
- `bash`... doesn't do anything useful here

In fact, you are telling Heroku to run `bash python manage.py migrate`, where you run `bash` and pass it `python manage.py migrate` as arguments. Since `python` is not a shell script, `bash` cannot execute it.

Lose the `bash`:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate --app appName
```

Comment: Hi, even after removing the bash and just run "heroku run python manage.py migrate --app appName" from Terminal, I still get the same error, which is "bash: manage.py: command not found"

Comment: @codeSapience, something's wrong there. It looks like you removed _`python`_ from the command instead of `bash`. Are you entirely sure you didn't accidentally run `heroku run bash manage.py migrate --app appName`?

Comment: However, thanks for your help. I later found how to bypass this bottleneck and I already added that as an answer to the question.

Comment: Yes @Chris, I ran exactly what you posted " heroku run python manage.py migrate --app appName " in my terminal. And of course, replaced appName with my app name.

Comment: @codeSapience, that is very surprising. Please edit a screenshot into your question.

Comment: I've done that.

Comment: @codeSapience, thank you. Do you have a `Procfile`? If so, please add its contents to your question. And are your using Docker to deploy? If so, please show your `Dockerfile`.